# touch: cannot touch file: No such file or directory

Tags: files, utilities, touch

I am getting the error:

```
touch: cannot touch `/opt/tsrm/compliance/cme/log/20121207.log`: No such file or directory
```

on the touch command: `touch $LOGFILE`

I also checked the link: [touch: cannot touch `foo': No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/touch-cannot-touch-foo-no-such-file-or-directory), But I didn't understand the answer.

Note: I was also getting `mkdir: cannot create directory`; I fixed this by adding the `-p` option.

Could this be something with the version of Linux I am working in?

Comment: explanation pretty simple, if the folder your were in was destroy when you invoke touch then it fails.

Comment: Ah yes, the "MC Hammer error"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You do not have the path that holds the file:

`/opt/tsrm/compliance/cme/log/`

That's where the error come from.

Comment: I would call that a *directory* not a path

Comment: `mkdir -p /opt/tsrm/compliance/cme/log`

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you misspelled the path. For example, this folder `/stuff/more_stuff` does not exist. This gives me the result:

```
user@linux:~ $ touch /stuff/more_stuff/stuff.file
touch: cannot touch `/stuff/more_stuff/stuff.file': No such file or directory
```

Both `/stuff` and `/stuff/more_stuff` need to exist in order for `touch` to work.

Comment: In my case I am trying to use `touch /etc/resolv.conf` and it says `touch: cannot touch '/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory`. `/etc` definitely does exist.

Comment: Have you checked if `resolv.conf` is a symlink to a file that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 9):

As silly as this reply sounds, other than missing directory, there could be string delimiter surrounding the value in `$LOGFILE`

Working:

```
LOGFILE=/stuff/more_stuff/stuff.file
touch $LOGFILE
```

Not Working:

```
LOGFILE="/stuff/more_stuff/stuff.file"
touch $LOGFILE
```

Some Linux distro have the quirk above, so be careful ;)

Comment: seems this is what is causing problem on GitLab CI

Answer (score 6):

Yes there might be chances of miss typo or directory not exists .

```
LOGFILE="/opt/tsrm/compliance/cme/log/20121207.log"
LOG_DIR=`dirname $LOGFILE`
[ ! -d $LOG_DIR ] && mkdir -p $LOG_DIR
touch $LOGFILE
```